# How to create and emit custom event with Combine and Swift?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a class that I want subscribe by multiple subscribers. How can I achieve something like this (consider as pseudo code)? Does it possible to implement such events easily without implementing manually Subscription, Publisher with lots of code?

In short, it should be upgraded Delegate pattern. And it could handle Void events potentially. Just creating a Published property of type ([Item], [Item]) is not the case because event with the same repeated data can be sent one by one.

```
class SomeObservedClass: ObservableObject {
    //???
}

//We will have multiple listeners like this
class SomeListener1 {
    @Published var observedClass: SomeObservedClass
    
    init() {
        observedClass = .init()
        
        //Maybe something like this
        observedClass
            .publisher(for: .listChanged)
            .sink { (addingItems: [Item], removingItems: [Item]) in
                //Processing data
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
        
        //Or something like this maybe
        observedClass
            .onReceive(.listChanged) { (addingItems: [Item], removingItems: [Item]) in
                //Processing data
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this question?  If I understand what you are asking, I am basically trying to figure out how to do something similar.  I cannot figure out how to handle the situation in Combine when a publisher is a collection (array, set, etc), the subscribers' sink only receives the entire collection when it changes, but I would like to know which specific item was added or removed from the published collection that caused the publisher to publish an update.  I have not yet figured out how to do this with Combine.

Comment: Hey John. Yep, I've managed to create a nice working solution. Thanks for asking, cuz I've forgot to add an answer here... Please check my answer below, it works well on the real project now, multiple subscribers receive events like a charm.
We can also publish Void if we don't need any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution utilising PassthroughSubject. For now the shortest and cleanest one I could produce. Tested with multiple subscribers, works like expected.

```
class MainClass {
    private let sequenceManager: SequenceManager = .init()
    private var bucket: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    func subscribeMe() {
        //Here is how we use our publisher
        sequenceManager
            .publisher(for: .onSequenceUpdate)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) //Optionally
            .sink { (addingItems, removingItems) in
                //Handle new data here
            }
            .store(in: &bucket)
    }
}

//Object we want to publish its changes
class SequenceManager {
    private let sequencePublisher = UpdatedSequencePublisher()
    
    private func didUpdate(addingItems: [String], removingItems: [String]) {
        //Here we publish changes
        sequencePublisher.publish(adding: addingItems, removing: removingItems)
    }
}

//Our publisher stuff
extension SequenceManager {
    struct UpdatedSequencePublisher: Publisher {
        typealias Output = (adding: [String], removing: [String])
        typealias Failure = Never
        private let passThroughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            passThroughSubject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
        
        func publish(adding: [String], removing: [String]) {
            passThroughSubject.send((adding, removing))
        }
    }
    
    func publisher(for event: Event) -> UpdatedSequencePublisher {
        switch event {
        case .onSequenceUpdate:
            return sequencePublisher
        }
    }
    
    enum Event {
        case onSequenceUpdate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this.  Yes, this is very helpful and seems to offer the functionality that I'm looking for.  I have continued to read Combine documentation, but the ability to know which item was added or removed from a publisher that is a collection just does not seem to exist out of the box in the Combine framework, so what you've got here is very helpful.